# Accessing a pointer in a struct that is in a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

An error is thrown, and I'm not sure sure why:

> physics.c:74: error: incompatible types in initialization

```
typedef struct gameBody gameBody;

struct gameBody
{
    cpBody *body;
    int numberOfShapes;
    cpShape *arrayOfShapes; //This stores an array of pointers to Shapes
};

//Struct that stores the cpSpace object and the array of pointers to the body objects
typedef struct gameSpace gameSpace;

struct gameSpace
{ 
    cpSpace *space;
    int numberOfObjects;
    gameBody *arrayOfObjects;       //This stores an array of gameBodys
};


for(int i = 0; i < space -> numberOfObjects; i++)
{
    //body info
    gameBody *gBody = space -> arrayOfObjects[i];
}
```

Comment: You are double-posting the same question within 25 minutes!

Comment: Instead of posting a question for each and every different compiler error, do this. 1. Post a question. 2. Read and understand the answer. 3. Use that understanding to fix the multiple identical errors in your code. 4. Don't post a new question without first checking to see whether or not it's the exact same question you posted 20 minutes ago!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's in the line

```
gameBody *gBody = space -> arrayOfObjects[i];
```

While `space->arrayOfObject` is a pointer, `space->arrayOfObject[i]` *is not* a pointer.

You either have to declare `gBody` to not be a pointer:

```
gameBody gBody = space->arrayOfObjects[i];
```

Or use the address-of operator on the object in the array;

```
gameBody *gBody = &space->arrayOfObjects[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 gameBody *gBody = &(space -> arrayOfObjects[i]);
```

or

```
gameBody *gBody = space -> arrayOfObjects + i;
```

Answer (score 0):

`gBody` is of type `gameBody *`, and `space->arrayOfObjects[i]` is of type `gamebody`.  Perhaps you want:

```
gameBody *gBody = &space->arrayOfObjects[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've posted

`gameBody *gBody = space->arrayOfObjects[i]` <~ is the problem...

which should be:

`gameBody *gBody = &(space->arrayOfObjects[i]);`